# Improve text to code ratio on pages using JSRender templates

Tags: javascript, html, seo, webmethod, jsrender

I have been experimenting using JSRender to build dynamic pages. It works well, but is trashing the text to code ratio of the site. What can I do about this?

http://tinyurl.com/cqbryjy

The ratio is 2.18%, when 15% is recommended.

Comment: "15%" is recommended by who and for what purpose?

Comment: It is standard SEO advice to stay on the right side of Google and avoid a site being considered spam, especially since its Panda update. http://blog.woorank.com/2013/03/are-text-to-html-ratios-important/

Comment: that article says a "good text to HTML ratio is anywhere from 25 to 70 percent.", which is the first i've seen of this figure, so who is recommending 15%?